# My algorithm is too slow

Tags: algorithm

I have an algorithm that for an integer `x` and a starting integer `i` such that 1 < `i` < `x` the next value of `i` is computed by `i = floor(x / i) + (x mod i)`. This continues until we reach an `i` that we've already seen.

In JavaScript (though this question is language agnostic):

```java
function f(x, i) {
    var map = {};
    while(!map[i]) {
        map[i] = true;
        i = Math.floor(x / i) + (x % i); // ~~(x / i) is a faster way of flooring
    }
    return i;
}
```

I can prove that we will eventually reach an `i` we've already seen, but I'm wondering:

1. Is there is a more efficient way of computing the next `i`?
2. (More importantly) Is there is a way to compute the nth `i` without running through the loop `n` times?

---

Just to clarify - I know there are faster ways than using JS hash maps for that check, and that flooring can be replaced by integer division in other languages. I have made both of those optimizations, but I left them out to try to make the code easier to understand. Sorry for any confusion.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this some known mathematical problem like Collatz conjecture?

Comment: @MBo not that I know of. It stemmed from a side-project I was working on. If it is related to a known mathematical problem that'd be great to know! I did a search a few weeks ago for similar mathematical problems but couldn't come up with anything, and having not improved much on the problem, decided to ask others for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main time eater - map. It uses some hashing function (probably not simple). If `i` range is limited by reasonable value, it would better to use bit/boolean array (or Javascript analog)

The second  - two divisions. Are floats and integers distinct in Javascript? It is possible to make one integer division, finding modulo with multiplication and subtraction (due to fundamental properties of integer division/modulo definition):

```
p = x \\ i
i = p + (x - p * i)
or
i = x - (x \\ i) * (i - 1)
```

Note: integer division in most processors calculates both quotient and residue in the same time

```
mov eax, 17          //dividend
mov ecx, 3           //divisor
xor edx, edx         //zero
div ecx              //edx:eax pair divide by ecx
//now eax contains quotient 5, edx contains residue (modulus) 2
```

If you can use asm in C, or have some functions like delphi [DivMod](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Math.DivMod), you can make calculations some faster.

Comment: Yeah sorry in my c implementation I do have a faster check than the JS `map` but thanks for pointing that out! I should have clarified - I just wrote it in JS to make it easily readable. Sorry can you clarify the second bit. Are you saying the `floor` is a second division and can be removed? I do have that covered in my C implementation as well, sorry I'll clarify both of those points in the question

Comment: Yes, one division could be removed, and all float stuff too.

Comment: great I'll take a look. Thanks! I'll close this out here and migrate it to programmers.stackexchange.com as that might be the more appropriate platform for this type of question.